# How to perform Unit Testing on Create method in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

How to perform a Unit testing on MVC application?

I have created the Controller Location.
It has properties like LocationName,Area,City,PinCode.

Now, I want to perform unit test to check whether Location saves in DB or not. 
How to check it.

I have go through tons of videos, every where they just put the Unit test of 
Mathematical operations like adding,Dividing , subtracting....

I would like to know how to perform the Unit testing of Create method of MVC

I have code something like below

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Locations.Add(location);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the `db` variable? Where does it come from? How is it initialized? Did you abstract your data access layer behind an interface or is this `db` your EF database access context because if it is you can simply forget about unit testing this code in isolation because it is strongly tied to a specific data provider.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make your code testable, you should abstract dependencies of controller. It's very handy to use [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern to abstract data access. [Inject](http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/index.php/2011/05/ninject-and-entity-framework-code-first-easy-repository-patterns/) your repository into controller:

```
public class LocationController : Controller
{
    private ILocationRepository _locationRepository;

    public LocationController(ILocationRepository locationRepository)
    {
         _locationRepository = locationRepository;
    }
}
```

Now you can mock your repository. Here is sample test with [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) framework and [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper):

```
// Arrange
Mock<ILocationRepository> repository = new Mock<ILocationRepository>();
var controller = new LocationController(repository.Object);
Location location = new Location("New York);
// Act
var result = controller.Create(location);
// Assert
result.AssertActionRedirect()
      .ToAction<LocationController>(c => c.Index());
repository.Verify(r => r.Add(location));
repository.Verify(r => r.Save());
```

And you can implement code, which will pass this test:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Location location)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _locationRepository.Add(location);
        _locationRepository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
}
```

You can read more on implementing repositories and testing MVC applications here:
[Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Nice feature also to have [Unit of Work per request](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/12/using-the-unit-of-work-per-request-pattern-in-aspnet-mvc/).

Comment: DB is Context Class, so whether I am able to use Unit test or not ?

Comment: No, you can't mock context. Wrap it (e.g. with repository), and then mock wrapper. See my link about repositories and uof in ASP.NET MVC. Also you can extract interface which your db context implements, and use that interface in controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support... but I am new to MVC... I didn't get anything from your link...Is any other way to check it ? I just want test whether record saves in DB or not.

Comment: If you want to check if record saved in database, then you need integration testing with real database. For controller's unit tests you should only verify that `Save` method is called on repository interface.