# How to unit test a create method with unit of work implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to unit test a create method that has unit of work implemented for a school project. I read many tutorials about unit testing but didn't find anything similar to my task, except another unit testing question on a create method on "stackOverflow" but I didn't know how to use that to resolve my task.
Can you please guide me to the right direction. 
Thanks

This is a snippet of the Create method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Code,Description")] LocationCode locationCode)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            uow.LocationCodeRepository.Insert(locationCode);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(locationCode);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into Mock? In this case you want to test the business logic - and mock out the actual repository/data/service access whatever it is.

Comment: I tried Moq but I got stucked...I tried to apply something from this answer [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664778/how-to-perfrom-unit-testing-on-create-method-in-mvc)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

using moq you can mock unit of work to simulate it's execution

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/basic-introduction-to-writing-unit-tests-with-moq/16

Comment: Like I said I am a beginner and in this tutorial doesn't explain in detail some aspects. I understood what mocking is, but just in theory. The code it's not explained very good (just partially). If I were more advanced I am sure it could used that. I have to keep reading other tutorials about DAL unit testing. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my teacher and he explained me that this type of method it is not suitable for unit testing in real life projects.A unit test can be done to show that the data is saved in the database but just for demonstrative purposes.